# Avoiding duplicates to same recipient when sending the same e-mail to multiple Mailgun lists

Tags: php, mailgun

I’m just starting the process of transferring our company newsletter to Mailgun; I haven’t actually migrated anything yet, so thus far, this is mostly a theoretical question (hence no actual code to show)—but it’s one that has a great deal of impact on *how* the migration will be implemented.

Our newsletter is somewhat complex in that people don’t just sign up for a generic newsletter, but to specific topics. Whenever we send out a newsletter, we choose which topics are relevant and then send out to people subscribed to those topics. Naturally, there is often overlap, so that the same e-mail address is subscribed to several different topics.

My initial thought was to simply create one Mailgun mailing list for each topic (currently 32 in all) and then import all subscribers into that mailing list. This seems the easiest and most flexible solution, but I don’t know what happens if I send out a newsletter to, say, five different topics/mailing lists and there are e-mail addresses that appear in several of those lists.

I’m assuming that Mailgun will simply send the message to all subscribers of each list, so someone who is subscribed to all five topics will just receive the e-mail five times; but I cannot find any mention of this scenario in their documentation, in the issues on their Github, or even on Google in general.

**How does Mailgun handle a situation like this? And if my assumption is correct that it doesn’t do anything to avoid duplicates out of the box, is there a way to make sure that a unique newsletter is sent only once to each e-mail address, regardless of how many lists that e-mail address is a member of?**

(In case it matters, the individual lists vary in size from about a hundred up to a couple of thousand subscribers. The total number of subscribers to all lists combined is just over 2,000, so we’re not talking massively huge lists here.)

Comment: Sounds like a good question to ask directly to Mailgun support?

Comment: @LeszekRepie There isn’t really a dedicated Mailgun support for this kind of thing, as far as I can tell—their support pages suggest asking here on StackOverflow or opening a support ticket. I figured I’d try the former before the latter. :-)